# How to send email from React App using AWS tools

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-amplify

What is the recommended way to send emails from a react app which is deployed on AWS. I understand that AWS SES - Simple mail service exists. How can I use the same in a React App ? I am using Amplify tool chain if that helps.

Comment: its a bad idea to send email directly from the web browser - you should consider using an web application web server.

Comment: @DanielA.White -  Can I use aws lambda to do the same ?

Comment: Yep that will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to create lambda function and inside lambda function invoke SES.

2) once you done with step 1 ,go to api getway create api and give proper role ,policy and core access.

3) Deploy your api in stage and call api in ur reactive native app .